# Multi-colored circle with transparent inner border

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm nearly there with this, but am struggling with making a transparent inner border.  Here's a link to what I would like to achieve: [Multi-colored circle with transparent inner border](https://codepen.io/snarf1974/pen/aywZZJ)

This is what I've done so far:
[Multi-colored circle with grey centre circle][2]

Here is the scss:

```
@mixin circle($size) {
content: "";
position: absolute;
border-radius: 50%;
left: calc(50% - #{$size/2});
top: calc(50% - #{$size/2});
width: $size;
height: $size;
}

$wheel: 20em;
$colors: (#f9a260, #f57d42, #f0463e, #c14273, #86489b, #008fca, #00bced, 
#00b8a9, #82ba75, #9bcb61, #f6e04e, #f4c64d);

.m-callout3 {
overflow: hidden;
width: $wheel;
height: $wheel;
position: relative;
&__colours {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
&__colour {
    @include circle($wheel);
}
&__colour, &__colour:nth-child(n+7):after {
    clip: rect(0, $wheel, $wheel, #{$wheel/2});
}
&__colour:after, &__colour:nth-child(n+7) {
    @include circle($wheel);
    clip: rect(0, #{$wheel/2}, $wheel, 0);
}
@for $i from 0 to length($colors) {
    &__colour:nth-child(#{1+$i}):after {
        background-color: nth($colors, $i+1);
        @if $i < 6 {
            transform: rotate(#{30*(1+$i)}deg);
            z-index: #{length($colors)-$i};
        } @else {
            transform: rotate(#{-30+(30*(1+$i))}deg);
        }
    }
}
&__center {
    @include circle($wheel - 2em);
    background: $dark-gray;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 13;
}
&__content {

    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5em;
    p {
        font-size: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    span {
        font-family: $font-light;
        font-size: 1em;

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="m-callout3">
<div class="m-callout3__center">
    <div class="m-callout3__content">
        <p>£3 million</p><span>Business Centre</span>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="m-callout3__colours">
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
    <div class="m-callout3__colour"></div>
</ul>
```

If anyone could shed some light, I would be most grateful.

** Nearly at the promised land!! Just struggling to have all 12 colour sections, there's 11 at the moment: https://codepen.io/snarf1974/pen/aywZZJ

Can anyone shed any light? **

Comment: Here is something that might help you - https://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/mrcejw0p/

Comment: AFAIK, you can't actually have a ring using html and css unless you are using SVG's or Canvas. You will have to use the background color.

Comment: @SGS Venkatesh This is exactly what I'm looking for, but is it possible to add the 12 separate colours to the outer circle?

Comment: Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/snarf1974/pen/VzKVLZ

Comment: Careful, when using the solution suggested by @snarf1974. `clip` css property is supported on limited devices and is deprecated. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Comment: Thanks for the info @SGS Venkatesh, I've tried to replace `clip` with `clip-path` but it just turns it all orange, instead of the 12 colours.

Comment: `clip-path` too is an experimental technology. Go ahead only if you are sure that you don't need extensive cross browser support. However, I strongly suggest that you do this with SVG's.

Comment: Here is a pen for one such rainbow wheel - https://codepen.io/sgsvenkatesh/pen/dzpaZQ